# How can I convince my boss to make me project-lead in an upcoming project?

Tags: communication, leadership, teamleader

There is a new project coming up with a new customer. It's using technologies which some of my colleagues are more experienced with. It sounds like a great project to me and it seems like a good chance to prove myself.
I'm sure I can do that but I don't have any own experience leading a team. The team-size is gonna be somewhere between 4-7 people.

How can I convince my boss in a brief mail to make me becoming project lead? Well - or at least to consider it.

My boss loves emails and does not find time to have personal meetings. As in he don't like them and basically only communicates per mail/chat.

Answer (score 3):

While, to you, this is "good chance to prove" yourself, your boss's job is to put together the team most likely to be successful:  The gap from being an individual contributor to leading a team of 4-7 is very significant, and he/she is going to need lots of convincing.

First, I think you need to catalog all the instances where you "acted like" a leader - situations where you resolved conflicts between others; examples where you assigned, reviewed, and re-assigned work to others; instances of evaluating different approaches and picking the best option for the circumstances; examples of managing competing priorities; etc.

Once you have that list of examples, you should look it over and see if you can convince yourself that you actually have what it takes to successfully lead such a project.  If you can convince yourself, then essentially that list of examples becomes the core of your argument.

If, after careful consideration, you haven't convinced yourself, one approach to take would be to ask your boss to provide you with opportunities so that you can develop the skill required of a team leader, **so that you could be strongly considered for leadership next time.**  In fact, if you do attempt to convince your boss, and he/she disagrees, I think you should take the same approach: ask for opportunities to develop leadership skills.

Answer (score 1):

Having a deep interest/passion, self awareness about your strengths and weaknesses as a leader and demonstrating that interest is the first step.

Rather than sending an email, I would encourage you to spend 1-1 time with your boss to express why you want to lead and serve this team and why you believe you can do a great job. Even if you don't get the role because you don't have the requisite experience, it indicates that you have interest and there may be opportunities to gain that experience under the mentorship of someone more senior / experienced.

Congratulations on getting on the leadership journey! It's going to be very rewarding!